# Navigationrail leading/trailing align to left

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer, flutter-web, toolbar, flutter-animation

I have a `Navigationrail` widget with a button to extend/collapse it. `Trailing/leading` widgets in one line with `NavigationRailDestination` when `extend=false`, but when `extend=true` `trailing/leading` widgets always align to center.

Is it possible to align it to the left/right?

My goal: `trailing/leading` widgets should not change it's positions to center when `navigationrail` extended.

[image]

Comment: Can you include sample widget that will reproduce the same issue ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh It's default behaviour of Navigationrail. Just set trailing/leading widgets for it and dynamic changes of extended.
Here you can find last sample of what I mean:
https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-navigationrail-widget-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by editing this example: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail/extendedAnimation.html

**Solution:** use `Animation` of `NavigationRail`

```
final Animation<double> animation =
        NavigationRail.extendedAnimation(context);
```

and then change the width/padding according to it with lerpDouble function:

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        right: lerpDouble(0, 200, animation.value)!,
        bottom: 30,
      ),
```

Full working code:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavigationRailMenuButton extends StatelessWidget {

   const NavigationRailMenuButton({super.key, this.onPressed});
   final VoidCallback? onPressed;
   
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Animation<double> animation =
        NavigationRail.extendedAnimation(context);
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animation,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            right: lerpDouble(0, 200, animation.value)!,
          ),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
            iconSize: 32,
            onPressed: onPressed,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```